# Reuse input component with typescript and validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am making a simple form with validation of the [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#TypeScript) package. The fields in this form are reused components. When I use the hook of react-hook-form I indicate it as
`const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm<IFormDataSearchMovie>()`

Put when writing the onSubmit the types of the argument do not recognize it and it is highlighted:
`Binding element 'title' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

The **component of the form**:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { TextField } from '../TextField';
import { IFormDataSearchMovie } from '../../types';

export const ListOfMovies: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm<IFormDataSearchMovie>();

  const onSubmit = ({ title }) => {
    console.log(title);
  };

  return (
    <div className='ListOfMovies'>
      <h2>Lista de películas</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <TextField
          type='text'
          placeholder='Introduce el nombre de la pelicula'
          name='title'
          register={register({ required: true })}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The TextField prop `register` shows the following error:

```
Type '(ref: HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | (HTMLSelectElement & HTMLInputElement) | ... 12 more ... | null) => void' is not assignable to type '() => any'.ts(2322)
types.ts(17, 5): The expected type comes from property 'register' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITextFieldProps'
```

**Textfield component**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ITextFieldProps } from '../../types';

export const TextField = ({
  type,
  placeholder,
  name,
  register,
}: ITextFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <input
      type={type}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      name={name}
      ref={register}
    />
  );
};
```

**Interfaces**:

```
export interface ITextFieldProps {
    type: string,
    placeholder: string,
    name: string,
    register(): any, 
}

export interface IFormDataSearchMovie {
    title: string
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to type useform destructuring, onSubmit function and prop register?